Data Integrity S3 During Transit for Large File
I'm new to encryption, so my question might seem basic. Despite reading multiple articles, I'm still unsure if I fully understand.
I have an S3 bucket, bucket_a, which will be used by different AWS accounts to upload data. The frequency of file uploads can be as frequent as every 5 minutes, and the size of each file can vary from 1KB to 100MB. I want to ensure that the data uploaded to bucket_a is encrypted in transit with KMS for an added layer of security over TLS.
I attempted to encrypt the bucket with asymmetric KMS and provide the public key to clients for data uploads. However, encrypting larger data with the public key is failing.
Another approach I read about is hybrid encryption, where data is sent using a symmetric key and the symmetric key is encrypted with the public key. My confusion with this approach is:

How can services like Glue/Glue Crawler decrypt the file content? Do I need to explicitly handle this?
With the symmetric key approach, do I need to explicitly manage file decryption?

Can someone help answer these questions or guide me to resources that can help me understand this better?

How will the files be uploaded? Will it be done via a program, via the AWS CLI, via a web page? The data will be encrypted in transit by doing the upload with HTTPS and it will be encrypted at rest by having a default KMS key associated with the bucket. So, do you really need the file also encrypted by a public or symmetric key? That would prohibit services like Glue and Athena being able to use it. What is your particular driver for needing the file-level encryption?

File will be uploaded via program.
Data Integrity is reason for asymmetric key encryption.
HTTPS will encrypt data in transit but that's single layer of encryption, I want to add another layer as data is sensitive data.
